# Connect to network from listview

Tags: android, listview, onclick, wifi, connect

See my code below. This produces a listview with all available wificonnections.
My goal is too connect to one of those available connections listed.
I have tried several things but it won't work properly.
It's about filling the onclick property for the listview with the right code.
Can anybody help me out? Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.wifitester2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

   public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener
 {      
     WifiManager wifi;       
    ListView lv;
    TextView textStatus;
    Button buttonScan;
    int size = 0;
    List<ScanResult> results;

    String ITEM_KEY = "key";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,       String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;

/* Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
    buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
    buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) 
        {
            //Method to connect to the listview item
        }

    });

    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() == false)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wifi is disabled..making it enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }   
    this.adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main.this, arraylist, R.layout.row, new String[] { ITEM_KEY }, new int[] { R.id.list_value });
    lv.setAdapter(this.adapter);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) 
        {
           results = wifi.getScanResults();
           size = results.size();
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));                    
}



public void onClick(View view) 
{
    arraylist.clear();          
    wifi.startScan();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning...." + size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try 
    {
        size = size - 1;
        while (size >= 0) 
        {   
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();                       
            item.put(ITEM_KEY, results.get(size).SSID + "  " + results.get(size).capabilities);

            arraylist.add(item);
            size--;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }         
}    
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) 
{
    connectToWifi(arg2);
}

private void connectToWifi(int position)
{
    HashMap<String, String> item = arraylist.get(position);

    //get SSID and BSSID from item

    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration(); 
    wifiConfiguration.SSID = itemSSID; 
    wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.NONE); 
    wifiConfiguration.BSSID = itemBSSID; //you should also put the BSSID in the map
    wifiConfiguration.hiddenSSID = false; 

    int inetId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration); 
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(inetId, true);
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your input. Only one question, de itemSSID and itemBSSID are red underlined because they are not defined... can you help me with that? thanks in advance

Comment: Well I was not sure about the logic behind you HashMap. You need to fetch the String containing the SSID corresponding to a ITEM_KEY string that you generated somehow. Why haven't you inserted a ScanResult object as value for an ITEM_KEY in the HashMap? Or maybe you could just fetch it from the results arraylist using the position no if you have inserted elements in the list iteratively from the results list.

Comment: yes your last option is what i am doing now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: good code, but suppose the wifi is protected with a password, what will be the consequence ?